# Switch between nav-pills on large screen and navbar-nav on smaller screen with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav, nav-pills

I like the look of the nav pills on larger screens, but once the collapse button shows I want that menu to be stackable and look like the image attached instead of the pills.  Do I need custom css to make this happen?

```html
<div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".main-nav-collapse" aria-controls="main-nav-collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-nav-collapse">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills mr-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Want this on smaller screens

[image: NavBar-Nav]

Want these pills on larger screens but not smaller

[image: Nav Pills Only]

Comment: you can use `d-none` and `d-block` property here

Comment: Thanks, brother wait for my perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accomplished this with the below code.

```
<nav class="nav nav-pills mr-auto flex-column d-md-flex flex-md-row">
```

Comment: no problem with your answer but your question is not match with your answer.

Comment: It does match, you are reading "switch" as having TWO menus.  I am not meaning that but meaning the look of the same menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch those classes `d-none` and `d-flex` here.

Why `d-flex` here instead of `d-block` because `.nav` class are made using flexbox so flex is more comfortable than block.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- TILL 1200PX (XL) -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light d-flex d-xl-none">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- AFTER 1200PX (XL) -->
<ul class="nav d-none d-xl-flex">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I dont want to have two navs?

Comment: but you want navbar in smaller screen and nav-pills in a larger screen so, I suggest you to use both elements and switch between that.

Comment: I didn’t need to with my answer

Comment: are you happy with my answer or not?